# Rendering a list in basicfont.render in python

Tags: python, list, text, pygame

I am trying to make it so you can type into a specified box in python (not using the inputbox module), and am trying to render a list into text.  Here is the section of code :

```
    TypingUsername = []
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        KeyPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        TypingUsername.append(KeyPressed)
    LoginUsernameInput = basicFont.render('%d' %(TypingUsername), True, White, Black)
```

I am unsure of what to put into my basicFont.render ('%????') to import the list TypingUsername ('d' is my placeholder for right now').  If anyone could help me, that would be tremendous help!

Comment: Learn more about events.

Answer (score 1):

When `event.type` is `pygame.KEYDOWN` you can get only pressed key (`event.key`) and add to result string.

```
TypingUsername = ""

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN
        TypingUsername += event.key

LoginUsernameInput = basicFont.render(TypingUsername, True, White, Black)
```

Learn more about events: [pygame.event](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)

---

**by the way:** names with first upper letter should be use as class names - see [Naming Conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) in PEP 8. So use `typingUsername` or even `typing_username`, `login_username_input`. Constants like `White` should be in capital letters - `WHITE`, `BLACK`, `KEYDOWN`

```
typing_username = ""

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN
        typing_username += event.key

login_username_input = basicFont.render(typing_username, True, WHITE, BLACK)
```